# Shall we create a skiing tag in our site?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

Here is a [question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12305/how-to-train-muscle-which-goes-from-buttocks-to-the-waist) about skiing?

How would it be to create a new tag on `Skiing`?

Comment: Could be a bad question. Just had a doubt, that is why I am asking rather than suggesting.

Comment: Wait, what are you asking? How to create a new tag? Just retag or edit the question and add it.

Comment: @Matt Chan Just adding another tag will create a new tag in the community?

Comment: Yes. There's no point in adding a tag otherwise. That's what I meant in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only two tags on that question are currently [exercise](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exercise) and [muscle](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muscle). I would say go ahead and modify those and make them more specific as to what the content of the question is about. Bear in mind though that if a tag is only ever used on one question, it will be automatically culled after some time.

Also, the asked of the question doesn't seem to know the name of the specific muscle (or group of muscles) to train. It would be good to identify and clarify that too.

Comment: No, actually I think I've got to modify my question.

Comment: I just found some more skiing questions and added the tag to them, it probably wont disappear now.